# 1 px offset in my html layout (table, div)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a website and I stumbled over an issue that being a reall pain for me.

I started with the page layout but I'm getting an offset of 1px which I can't resolve and I need help. This is what I have now.

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('darkmetalgrid.jpg');
}
#PageContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#Page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
}
#Header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: red;
}
#Navigation {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#Body {
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

and this as html

```
<body>
    <div id="PageContainer">
        <table id="Page">
            <tr><td id="Header"></td></tr>
            <tr><td id="Navigation"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="Body">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

somehow the navigation cell keeps having a 1px offset to the right in all browsers. **`I tried the same with DIV's using "display : table" and without the table but I had exactly same result.**`

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

see website http://www.quyodev.be/

Comment: Your big mistake: using tables for layouts.

Comment: please provide demo page. you can't expect a human brain to parse your text as code and see what's going on. use JSBIN.

Comment: hmm, why are you using Tables and not Div. Div is the proper way to layout Website. Table is for populating tabular data.

Comment: Does the 1px offset appear here http://jsfiddle.net/yzPVG/ ?

Comment: Just for the fun of it I made this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fs5Hv/1/ - using a more traditional approach. How would you want it changed?

Comment: like I said I tried it in a DIV layout first. then I tried it again in a table layout. exact same thing happens in both layouts.

http://www.quyodev.be/

Comment: The reason why I made it with a table layout is because its the only way how I could get body height to fill remaining 100% of the page. and not the entire 100% height. with display : table it worked fine but then again I was forced to add text to it while my header doesn't require any text inside. I did not have this in a table.

Comment: @user3677584 Tables shouldn't be used for layouts. This is not what the `table` element is designed for, and goes against the HTML specification. If you want your `div` elements to render like tables, you can make use of CSS's `display` property values `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`.

Comment: I noticed that when the colors are the same that I do not have the offset. so I don't know what causes this offset to happen

Comment: thx user3677584 but I told you I already tried this with same result